# Can anyone suggest a good book on aircraft performance?

Tags: books

Im trying to find a good book pertaining to aircraft performance and I have come across a book by PJ Swatton quite a number of times while searched on the internet.

Is this a good book or are there any better books?

Comment: This is a purely opinion-based question that can't be answered objectively. How would you define "Good"?

Comment: In addition, it's way too broad. What kind of "performance?" Powerplant, aerodynamics, stability and control, etc.? Of a particular aircraft or class of aircraft? Without narrowing it down, your question literally asks about the entire body of aviation knowledge developed over the last >100 years.

Answer (score 2):

"Aerodynamics for Naval Aviators" ([free PDF](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/media/00-80t-80.pdf) or [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1619540177)) is a great introduction, and from there you can dive into more engineering theory books.

Comment: While the *question* isn't a great fit for Av.SE, this answer is absolutely spot-on. For those looking for more depth than a basic PPL groundschool, this book is pretty much *the* canonical standard.